# vim: Highlight quickfix selected line with color different than 'Search'

Tags: vim

What is the highlight group for the currently selected line in the quickfix window?

The selected line in the quickfix window uses `Search` for highlighting. I'd like to continue using yellow for `Search` highlighting, but use blue for quickfix selected line.

Answer (score 5):

Ingo Karkat's answer is right. It's indeed hard-coded in vim code.
I have created a patch - [QuickFixCurrentLine.patch](https://gist.github.com/anishsane/5125b87ea4cddb43985496abd26a43e7#file-quickfixcurrentline-patch) for vim8.

Patch is long enough to be posted here. Plus, it has mix of tabs and spaces. So, providing a link-only-answer.

EDIT:
The patch has got upstreamed in the latest vim code.
The name of the highlight has been changed to quickfixline instead of quickfixcurrentline.

Comment: Did you ever get around to submitting this upstream? (Edit: I see that you did — https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1080).

Answer (score 4):

The currently selected quickfix item is hard-coded to `Search`. You'd have to change the Vim source code and recompile to change this.

I see only limited ways to work around this with Vimscript. You could try to override the highlighting for the current line via `:match` / `matchadd()` (it has higher priority), but it would only cover the length of the text, not the entire line the original highlighting. Also, I think the currently selected item cannot be easily queried from Vim, so you'd have to hook into the quickfix-local `<CR>` mapping to update it, and stop using `:cnext` etc. to move to different errors.

```
:highlight BlueLine guibg=Blue
:autocmd BufReadPost quickfix match BlueLine /\%1l/
:autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> :execute 'match BlueLine /\%' . line('.') . 'l/'<CR><CR>
```

Comment: _"The currently selected quickfix item is hard-coded to Search"_ Do you know where it is hard-coded to `Search`? As such since vim8 is out and I am compiling it, I thought I could do the changes...

Comment: @anishsane Ah, great; I was just searching through the source code myself. If the patch is short, just add your own answer, and put it there. Alternatively, post as a Gist, and add a comment with the URL here.

Comment: Here it is: [QuickFixCurrentLine.patch](https://gist.github.com/anishsane/5125b87ea4cddb43985496abd26a43e7#file-quickfixcurrentline-patch)

Comment: Is there a way to suggest the patch for up-streaming to vim8? It could help others. Else, they can review and discard.

Comment: Vim's issue tracker is here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues; your patch is looking good (only a documentation update is missing), I would definitely welcome an inclusion in Vim. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: For a first review, posting a link to the Gist would be fine. They may ask you to create a pull request later, but I think they would be able to just use your patch as-is, too.